# @font-face flicker on every page load in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, font-face, flicker

I know that a certain amount of text flicker or FLOUT (even if its unnoticeable) is almost inevitable with @font-face. However im having an issue with IE8 where the flicker occurs on every single page load. It seems that unlike other browsers the font file isn't cached at all. Why could this be happening and are there any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive managed to fix this by adding caching rules for this file in the htaccess.